# contingency table=fisher test

Tags: chi-squared, contingency

**Hello everyone,
I am very new at R programming and I am having a particular issue creating a contingency table in the way that I want. I need to run fisher.test and I cannot get the table to work. I have two categorical variables tmt (a,d) and postneg (yes, no). However, the values that I need for this table are in a different column named (score).[Table with variables and values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teUUZ.png). I tried grouping the variables (tmt, postneg) and summarize adding the values of (score).**

```
summary_cramp_data <- cramp_data %>% group_by(tmt,postneg) %>% summarise(sum_score=sum(score))
```

**Then I tried creating a tibble table**

```
contingency <- summary_cramp_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = postneg, values_from = sum_score)
```

***The table looks like this:**
[Tibble table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FxgD.png)

**Finally I transformed the table to a matrix**

```
as.matrix(contingency)
```

**However when running fisher test I keep having this error:**

```
> fisher.test(contingency)

Error in fisher.test(contingency) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite
```

**I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue.
Thank you very much,
Danisa**